# Azure Web Job schedule time being ignored after successful deployment

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a handful of triggered Web Jobs I need to deploy, I've deployed one and everything looks good.

The next one I've deployed it seems to ignore the schedule time within the `Settings.Job` file for some strange reason, instead after the deployment has been successful it shows n/a within the Schedule column of the Web Job

My Settings.Hob file is:

```
{
  "schedule": "0 */15 * * * *"
}
```

Again nothing to out of the ordinary.

I've deleted the Web Job completely of Azure, done a fresh deployment and the issue still persists.

I've then decided to use Kudu and navigate to the Web Job directly and check the `Settings.job`, however when navigating to:

```
D:\home\data\jobs\triggered>
```

My recently deployed Web Job doesn't exists, yet it appears within the Web Job UI, I've also checked Continuous just to be on the safe side and again no reference there of it.

I can't seem to find any solutions on the web for this issue, has anyone experienced this?

Comment: how do you deploy your webjobs?

Comment: @IvanYang via Visual Studio, apologies I should have mentioned that.

Comment: did you create a console project in visual studio, then select publish as a wejob from visual studio, right?

Comment: @IvanYang that's correct

Comment: in visual studio, right click the settings.job file -> select properties -> check the "copy to output directory", see if it's set to "do not copy".

Comment: @IvanYang it's set as "Copy Always"

Comment: have you checked if there any files under "D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\Jobs\Triggered\your_wejob" in kudu?

Comment: @IvanYang navigating to D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\Triggered\web job name> in Kudu shows the web job, however the Settings.job file doesn't exists.

Comment: that's weird. Can you please re-build your webjob project in visual studio, then publish it again? and is there any something like .ignore rules locally prevent the settings.job? You can also directly upload the settings.job file to your kudu.

Comment: @IvanYang no rules in place to ignore the file, my first web job deployed successfully with no issues and that resides in the same visual studio project.  I have just changed the Build Action from "none" to "content" and it now seems to be picked up and deployed.  Weird that I never needed to set the Build Action on the first web job.

Comment: wow, added an answer for it. It may help others who have the same issue.

Comment: @IvanYang it's really bizarre, all other web jobs after that one in particular didn't need the Build Action, so weird.  Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that right click Settings.job file -> properties -> then for Build, select "content".

I just had this issue for one time(.net framework and .net core), next time, I don't need to set it to content.

It seems weird, if someone else knows the reason, please feel free to explain this behavior.

Comment: Also if this does not work, remember that continuous and triggered webjobs are living in different folders! I had an issue copying accidentally triggered webjob under the continuous folder ```TargetFolder: ${{ parameters.projectName }}\bin\$(buildConfiguration)\netcoreapp3.1\publish\App_Data\jobs\triggered\```